# Set a range for the cells under a merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need to set a range for the cells under a merged cells.
with the provided picture, the expected result is `Range("I2:K4")`

[image]

```
Sub SelectRange()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim rng As Range, LastRow As Long

    Set rng = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Attach*", After:=Range("A1"), _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
       LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no content in the column next to "Attachments" you can use `CurrentRegion` and `MergeArea`:

```vb
Sub SelectRange()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Set rngStart = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Attach*", After:=Range("A1"), _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set rngStart = rngStart.MergeArea

    Dim rngFinal As Range
    With rngStart
        Set rngFinal = .Offset(1).Resize(.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: There are some column adjacent to the merged cells, So using `CurrentRegion` is not reliable in this case.

Comment: I updated the solution - it now returns the width of the MergeArea of "Attach"

Comment: I tried and the range is far away the required range.

Comment: I think the updated code will still bust if the adjacent cells to ignore are to the left of the desired columns. Edit: Might be fixable by just putting `rngStart` in front of `.Offset`. Still could have too many rows but it's in the right direction.

Comment: It would have helped if your sample data had reflected the true scenario. Please check the updated version. I am assuming that `CurrentRegion` will return the correct amount of rows as OP used LastRow in his sample code.

Comment: My sample data had reflected the true scenario, as you can see I hided columns `A:H`

Comment: I tried and now it works correctly as it should. up-voted

Comment: If this is the solution: please mark it as answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
' Helper Sub to call the sub rangeUnderOf(..)
Sub findRangeUnder()
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = rangeUnderOf("Attach*")
   If Not r Is Nothing Then
      'YOUR CODE HERE TO DO ANYTHING WITH THE RANGE UNDER...
      r.Select
   End If
End Sub
```

General purpose function, it is called with a parameter that contains the String
we want to find and an optional one with the Worksheet in which we want to
search. If the cell we will find is a union of cells (merged cells) then it takes
into account the columns as well as the lines that have been merged in order to
return the correct range under the detected cell.

```
Function rangeUnderOf(searchStr As String, Optional ws As Worksheet = Nothing) As Range
   Dim rng As Range
   If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
   Set rng = ws.Cells.Find(What:=searchStr, After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
             SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
   If Not rng Is Nothing Then
      With rng.MergeArea
         Set rangeUnderOf = .Offset(1).Resize(.CurrentRegion.rows.Count - .rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
      End With
   End If
End Function
```